# How can I organize C++ code without thinking too hard about whether something is templated?

Tags: c++, templates, compilation, linker

(I feel like this must be a duplicate, but I can't find it).

Consider:

*airplane.hpp:*

```
template<class T>
void wings();

void tail();
```

Now...  where to define  `wings()` and `tail()`? I'd like to define them in the same place; I'd like not to think about the fact that `wings()` is templated and `tail()` isn't. Maybe you'll see why I sometimes write:

*airplane.hpp:*

```
template<class T>
void wings();

void tail();

#ifndef airplane_cpp
#define header
#endif
#include "airplane.cpp"
```

*airplane.cpp:*

```
#define airplane_cpp
#include "airplane.hpp"

template<class T>
void wings() { }

#ifndef header
void tail() { }
#endif
```

But surely that's not the best way.

**edit:** It seems it may be relevant to add that I'm programming on a TI DSP chip, where, according to [the docs](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15745-s07/www/c6xref/compiler_guide.pdf), the `inline` keyword has a defined consequence on generated code:

> The inline keyword specifies that a function is expanded inline at the point at
>   which it is called rather than by using standard calling procedures. The
>   compiler performs inline expansion of functions declared with the inline
>   keyword.

Comment: If it's a template, define it in the header file.  If it's not a template, it's your choice:  define it in the header file or in a .cpp file.  If you want to define everything in header files, go for it, though if your project becomes large you may suffer longer compile times.

Comment: I suffer multiple definitions at link time.

Comment: Yes -- is that an acceptable thing to use here? It felt kind of "dirty" specifying inline just to dodge a linker error.

Comment: @Owen `inline` exists for that purpose!

Comment: That's the primary use of `inline`. Please don't tell me that you really try to tell the compiler what code to generate in line!

Comment: @JerryCoffin Sadly to say, I don't have much choice! See my edit.

Comment: You have two choices: (1) Make everything inline and deal with the code bloat, or (2) Write templates and functions differently. Also, if your compiler treats inline as an order rather than a hint, it may also forcibly online templates, so you may want to check into that.

Comment: Why don't you have much choice? The options have been explained to you, so the choice is yours.

Comment: @abarnert That's a good point about templates; I hadn't considered that. The docs don't say, but they're pretty scarce on C++ in general...

Comment: Owen: If the docs don't say, you've got various ways to find out: 1. Write to TI and ask. 2. Find a public forum for users of the chip and/or toolchain and ask. 3. If the compiler is open source, read it. 4. Test as many variations as you can find. (One out-of-line template function proves it doesn't always force-inline, but of course you can never prove the contrary.)

Comment: A quick skim through the docs you linked implies that you're wrong. Compile with -pi -oi and it'll apparently work the same as most other compilers—that is, no forced ("Unguarded Definition-Controlled") inlining, but automatic inlining.

Comment: Templated functions and non-templated functions are different things and you should care about the difference. The question is, exaggerating a bit, equivalent to asking: I want to drive a car and pilot a plane, but I don't care which I am doing, I want to do exactly the same in both cases.

Comment: @abarnert True I may just end up doing that. A little nervous to change compilation options now on a huge piece of code I didn't write, but we'll see.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas all I really want is parametric polymorphism...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define all the functions in the header if you make them `inline`:

```
template<class T>
inline void wings() {}
// inline not really needed here, but if you don't want to think about it...

inline void tail() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be achieved using the keyword `export` in front of your template. Unfortunately this keyword has not gained considerable support across compilers.

In other words, practically speaking, you should define the body of your template in the header file.

From my point of view, compiler vendors should have do an effort to implement the same paradigm that is used for functions also for for templates. I.e. description of the interface should stay in the header files, description of the bodies bodies in cpp files. Everything should be combined together during linking. They has not done this. As we have it today, paradigms for functions and tempates are different. Templates are `compile time ony` entities.

Comment: ..and `export` has been removed in C++11.

Comment: Unfortunately? Have you read the report of EDG? Export - at least in the form it was specified in the 98-standard - is an abomination that should have never been in the standard in the first place. Hence the removal instead of a simple deprecation...

Comment: Maybe my wording was not fine. What is written in C++2003 is a disaster. They should not write this. The right direction is to put  delayed template instantiation into the object file and finish the job during the link time. C++11 repeated the mistake. Instead of fixing the problem and by the way giving exact spec on how to export templates from DLLs, they removed the feature and paved another decade for improper implementation. We have to live with this. Our wold is not perfect.